# MS Word showing "Cannot open the specified file" error when trying to open hyperlink pointing to PDF returned by API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, pdf-generation

We have the following snippet in a Web API action than handles PDF requests. The action renders the PDF correctly in browsers.

Everything is working fine, except for an issue that we came across today.

If a user copies a PDF link from the website into Word, Word does not open the file and displays  "Cannot open the specified file" error

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
return result;
```

The PDF opens with no issue in browsers (IE/Edge/FF/Chrome - mobile or desktop). Word version does not seem to be an issue - tried 2010 through Office 365 ProPlus.

**EDIT:** The reason I think it's related to the above code is because an actual PDF file from the same website can be linked from Word and Word will simply display an "unsafe content" warning but still allow you to open it, unlike the PDF from API.

**EDIT:**

- Office: Microsoft Word for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12130.20232) 32-bit
- Windows: Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit Version 1903 (OS build 18362.476)

Comment: It's a word permission issue see this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cannot-open-https-hyperlinks-to-pdf-documents-from/7262cd15-9d42-436b-9d0a-074882d25773). And user has to do the work around. Or if it is a domain computer some policy should be added for that.

Comment: @Eldar Word is opening PDFs from other websites with no issues

Comment: Your site has SSL?

Comment: @joym8 can you post an actual link that is not working in Word or the structure of the link?

Comment: @Eldar yes the site has SSL, and I've tried modifying the Word link to plain HTTP and that gave same result

Comment: @joeschwa here is the route template:  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "pdf-route",
                routeTemplate: "pdf/{id}/{title}",
                defaults: new { controller = "WebApiClient", action = "loadpdf", id = 0, title = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change the rendering of the PDF in some way to work better with Word, but I believe the issue may stem from the `ForceShellExecute` registry key that controls how Office processes hyperlinks. When the key is set to 0 (or is not present) Office applications use an internal Office process to launch hyperlinks. When set to 1, Office will use the Windows process (basically the same as if the user opened the link via Start | Run | paste link | Enter). If the `ForceShellExecute` registry key is set to 0 or not present, it is likely the reason Word does not wish to process the API-rendered PDF.

To test if this is the root cause, find/change the value or create the registry key using these steps (which are from [Error message when selecting hyperlink in Office: "Cannot locate the Internet server or proxy server"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/error-messages/cannot-locate-server-when-click-hyperlink):

**Important Note**

All versions of Office require that the `ForceShellExecute` key be located under the `9.0` registry subkey. If the `9.0` subkey does not exist, you will need to create it and the subsequent `Common`, `Internet`, and `ForceShellExecute` subkeys.

> In Registry Editor, browse to one of the following subkey (create the keys when they do not exist):
>
> For a 32 Bit version of Office on 64 bit version of Windows
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet\
>
> For a 32 Bit version of Office on 32 bit version of Windows
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet
>
> For a 64 Bit version of Office on 64 bit version of Windows
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet
>
> Make sure the Internet subkey is selected. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then select DWORD Value. Add the following registry value:
>
> Value Name: ForceShellExecute
>
> Double-click ForceShellExecute, and then set the Value data to 1.

Additionally, changing this key may affect other Office operations in your environment. The article

[Impact of using ForceShellExecute=1 in Office 2007, 2010 and 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/emeaoffice/2013/06/13/impact-of-using-forceshellexecute1-in-office-2007-2010-and-2013/)

speaks to these situations in detail.

Comment: So I created the Internet key and added the ForceShellExecute value and set it to 1. Still getting same message. I havent restarted the computer. Will try that later on

Comment: And yes, I created the Internet key under 16.0 because there was no 9.0

Comment: @joym8 you need to create the 9.0 key, the subkeys under it, and place the `ForceShellExecute` there. Hyperlinks access the 9,0 registry for all versions of Office. This is explained in the contents of the last link I provided. Apologies for not clarifying this in my answer. I will edit the answer now to include this.